# How can I define the types of an object variable in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this object variable in the class `a`:

```
class a {
  abc = {
    def: number = 22  // won't work
  }
  ghi: number = 23; // works

..
```

How can I define (inline without using an interface) the type of the variable `def` that is inside the object `abc`?

I tried using this syntax but it will not accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it could be - is to use assert and inlined declaration:

```
class MyClass {
  abc = <{ def : number }>{
    def: 1,
  };  
}
```

The same, but a bit more readable with explicit interface

```
interface IMyObject{
  def : number 
}

class MyClass1 {
  abc = <IMyObject>{
    def: 1,
  };  
}
```

Check it [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0A%20%20abc%20%3D%20%3C%7B%20def%20%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%7B%0A%20%20%20%20def%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IMyObject%7B%0A%20%20def%20%3A%20number%20%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyClass1%20%7B%0A%20%20abc%20%3D%20%3CIMyObject%3E%7B%0A%20%20%20%20def%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%20%20%0A%7D)

And why this?

```
class a {
  abc = {
    def: number = 22  // won't work
  }
  ghi: number = 23; // works
```

because the ghi is the member/property of class a - so it is just like this:

```
class MyClass {
  // standard way how to define properties/members of a class
  public obj: number;
  private other: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI. Without using a type assertion:

```
class a {
  abc : {def:number} = {
    def : 22  // Works
  }
  ghi: number = 23; // works
}
```

Note: in your case its best to let the compiler *infer* the type signature for you.