# How can we define object type interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript, interface

I want to define a interface with object and different types
 such as

```
export interface example {
   code: string;
   category : {
     name : string,
     reference: string,
     sequence : number
   };
}
```

In definition, there is no problem but after calling like

```
ex = {} as example;
ex.category.name ='electric;
```

this does not work and below error occurs

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

There are some similar subjects but they are not exactly related. ([How to define object in type script interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425407/how-to-define-object-in-type-script-interface)  or [How can I define the types of an object variable in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339590/how-can-i-define-the-types-of-an-object-variable-in-typescript))

I appreciate your assistance finding the solution.

Comment: You still have to create the first level object: `ex.category = {};`, or just go straight to `let ex = { category: { name: 'electric' } };`. The interface just describes the *shape*, you still have to build the right object (or write a class with a constructor, or provide default values).

Comment: Is there any wrong about the question?

Answer (score 2):

[Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) do not mean the object will definitely be of the shape you are asserting at runtime. You can assert any object is of any type, but ultimately it will fail at runtime if your runtime type does not match.

In your example, the `ex` object does not have a `category` property so it will be `undefined` at runtime which leads to your error.

You can initialize the `category` property as well in your object:

```
var ex = {
    category: {} // or you can initialize `name` here as well
} as example;
ex.category.name = 'electric';
```

Comment: thanks , this answer helped me clear a very basic doubt. I was stuck for a full day. All other posts explained about creating a class, initializing the interface. but if the interface is big, adding a chunk of code for just initializing all the objects is not done.